# Select duplicate records with different values on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table:

```
**URL       | Answer**
google      |  NULL
google      |  NULL
google      |  NULL
yahoo       |  Yes
hotmail     |  NULL
hotmail     |  No
```

---

I want to select all the records that have the same URL but have only Answer NULL, in this case google & NULL. If URL has one NULL & No or Yes, those I don't need like the ones for hotmail.

```
SELECT DISTINCT URL
FROM Table
WHERE URL IN (
    SELECT URL
    FROM Table
    WHERE Answer IS NULL
    GROUP BY URL
    HAVING Count(*)  >= 1   
    );
```

Comment: You answer would fail if google also had a not null

Comment: Exactly. If google change any of the answers to Yes or No, the query will not select any of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `HAVING Count(*)  >= 1` you don't need to count.

> ```
> create table tbl (URL nvarchar(max), Answer varchar(10));
> insert into tbl values
> ('google', NULL),
> ('google', NULL),
> ('google', NULL),
> ('yahoo', 'Yes'),
> ('hotmail', NULL),
> ('hotmail', 'No');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT URL
> FROM   tbl
> WHERE  Answer IS NULL
> GROUP BY URL
> HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | URL    |
> | :----- |
> | google |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf51b1262fc2134aac4ed7037ad6e7fe)*

Or just to ensure all rows are null:

> ```
> SELECT t1.URL
> FROM   tbl t1
> WHERE  t1.Answer IS NULL
> AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
>                    FROM   tbl
>                    WHERE  URL = t1.URL
>                    AND    Answer IS NOT NULL)
> GROUP BY t1.URL
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | URL    |
> | :----- |
> | google |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3b26d7c892e832fea090e734a9eacb7)*

Comment: I don't think he wants hotmail or even single null

Comment: @paparazzo `HAVING Count(*)  >= 1`

Comment: I need to evaluate which duplicate URL have only NULL as an answer. For example I need my output to be google only since hotmail has one null and one No.

Comment: Not going to argue with you.  Not how I read the requirement.

Comment: @McNets it work, but a quick question if I change both the answers of hotmail to NULL, that as well I need to select. What should I do in that case? btw thanks for everything.

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a `DISTINCT` on your query.  There is no need to use `HAVING Count(*) >= 1` or a subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT URL
FROM Table
WHERE Answer IS NULL
```

Will give you the following output

```
google
hotmail
```

The condition `WHERE Answer IS NULL` will give you all that have a `NULL` Answer and `Distinct` will ensure that all the URL's are unique.

Comment: Yeah but I need to evaluate all the NULL answers by URL, for example I need my output to be google only since hotmail has one null and one No.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the URLs with NULL just do:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT URL
FROM Table
WHERE URL IS NULL
```

If you want the counts:

```
SELECT DISTINCT URL, count(*) as count
    FROM Table
    WHERE URL IS NULL
GROUP BY URL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is good

```
declare @T table (URL nvarchar(max), Answer varchar(10));
insert into @T values
('google', NULL),
('google', NULL),
('google', NULL),
('yahoo', 'Yes'),
('hotmail', NULL),
('hotmail', 'No');
select t.URL 
from @T t
group by t.URL
having max(t.Answer) is null 
   and count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Almost, cause if I change one of the answers of google to Yes it keep selecting google, when none should be selected. But this was helpful. thanks

Comment: @user9541932 It does NOT select google if you change and answer to yes.  You should have a more complete test case and desired output.